# Iterate function and write to new column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a pandas dataframe with one column containing some text on each row, and another column that is empty. Using a function I have, I would like to exact the named entities from each row and write the names of the entities and their types in the empty column. However, I'm not entirely sure how I would call the function on each row in the first column, and write the result to the same row in the second column.

Initially, the Dataframe would look somewhat like this:[image]

However, after calling the function, the entity column should be filled in with the entities within the text.

This is what I've got so far

```
import os
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

root = '/Users/ben/documents/humanotics/intent model/'
incorpus = root + '/chats/test.csv'
outcorpus = root + '/chats/output.csv'
entities = ['ORGANIZATION','PERSON','LOCATION','DATE','TIME','MONEY','PERCENT','FACILITY','GPE']

df = pd.DataFrame()
data = pd.read_csv(incorpus, header=None, names=['text','entities'])
df = df.append(data)

def findEntity(text):
    try:
        entity_names = []
        entity_names_lc = []
        for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(incorpus):
            for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
                if hasattr(chunk, 'label') and chunk.label:
                    for e in entities:
                        if chunk.label() == e:
                            name_value = ' '.join(child[0] for child in chunk.leaves())
                            if name_value.lower() not in entity_names_lc:
                                entity_names.append(name_value)
                                entity_names_lc.append(name_value.lower())
    except:
        print ("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])

    print(entity_names_lc)

    return

df.to_csv(outcorpus)
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: how does the dataframe looks liek after calling it ?

Comment: @BenoitDrogou That's what I mean, I'm not sure on how to call my function for each row. There are various iterating functions like iterrows() for example but I don't know whether to use them

Comment: pretty sure its a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use apply

```
def f(x):

 #do_somthing
 return value_to_store_in_second_col_at_same_row
df['second_col'] = df['first_col'].apply(lambda x:f(x))
```